# T/SQL LDAP Query To Get True lastLoginTimestamp Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, ldap, linked-server

I have SQL code that successfully retrieves user data, including the lastLoginTimestamp value. Now, the issue is we have multiple DC Servers, and the lastLoginTimestamp value typically propagates across servers only when another server's value is 14 days old. This means that in order to obtain the "true" lastLoginTimestamp value, you need to query each DC Server for their own local value and take the highest value at the true lastLoginTimestamp value.

My question is ... how do you query each server independently?

Below is my code which works, but only queries one server (which apparently is auto-chosen for me?). So my question is ... how, in SQL, do I query each Domain Controller (dynamically), so that I can get the latest value for lastLoginTimestamp?

```
-----------------------------------------
-- Initialize Variables
-----------------------------------------
DECLARE @strSQL         NVARCHAR(MAX)

-----------------------------------------
-- Retrieve All AD Users In My OU
-----------------------------------------
SET @strSQL =
'SELECT sAMAccountName,
        Mail,
        DistinguishedName,
        whenCreated,
        lastLogonTimestamp,
        pwdLastSet
    FROM ''''LDAP://MyDomain.com/OU=Users,OU=MyGroup,DC=MyDomain,DC=com''''
    WHERE objectClass = ''''User''''
'

-----------------------------------------
-- Wrap SQL in OpenQuery Command
-----------------------------------------
SET @strSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT
                  sAMAccountName AS UserName,
                  Mail AS EMail,
                  whenCreated AS CreatedOnDate,
                  CASE
                    WHEN (lastLogonTimestamp IS NULL) THEN NULL
                    WHEN (CAST(lastLogonTimestamp AS BIGINT) = 0) THEN NULL
                    ELSE CAST((CAST(lastLogonTimestamp AS BIGINT) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) S DATETIME)
                  END AS LastLogon,
                  CASE
                    WHEN (pwdLastSet IS NULL) THEN NULL
                    WHEN (CAST(pwdLastSet AS BIGINT) = 0) THEN NULL
                    ELSE CAST((CAST(pwdLastSet AS BIGINT) / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME)
                  END AS LastPWReset
            FROM OPENQUERY([MyLinkedServer], ''' + @strSQL + ''')
          '

-----------------------------------------
-- Execute Statement
-----------------------------------------
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @strSQL
```

Comment: I would run one query per server and store each result in a table. I would then run a select statement against that local table and user the MAX() function along with apropriate groupings to get the latest date.

Comment: @wenzzzel Thanks, but unfortunately, that isn't helpful because as I mentioned I do not know each individual DC. All I have is the LDAP URL described above, which links me to whichever available DC there is at the time (I assume using load-balancing). I need a "dynamic" way to pull out what each DC is in order to get all the required values, which is what I am asking for here in my OP. Thanks for responding though, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First things first - this is better (and more easily) achieved outside of SQL Server.  But, circumstances are often what they are so...

The problem you face is that the list of domain controllers (DC's) in an Active Directory domain / forest can be dynamic query to query as DC's are added and removed and, as you've pointed out, a generic query will bind to a domain controller that the provider decides is the best.  At a very high level, a DC is typically located with a DNS query which is difficult (at best) to perform from within SQL Server.  You can, however, do a directory query against the AD Global Catalog for a list of DC's.

This should get you a list CN's and DN's of all DC's in the domain / forest.

```
SELECT cn
FROM OPENQUERY(adsi, 'SELECT cn, distinguishedName
    FROM ''GC://MyDomain.com/DC=MyDomain,DC=COM''
    WHERE objectClass = ''computer''
    and userAccountControl = 532480'
)
```

(Note: 532480 is the UAC value for Domain Controller - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties) for reference)

You can slightly modify your existing code to iterate over that result list so that you can bind directly to each domain controller discovered from the query above:

```
DECLARE @CN VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @DN VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE DC_LIST CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT cn, distinguishedName
FROM OPENQUERY(adsi, 'SELECT cn, distinguishedName
    FROM ''GC://MyDomain.com/DC=MyDomain,DC=COM''
    WHERE objectClass = ''computer''
    and userAccountControl = 532480'
);

OPEN DC_LIST;
FETCH NEXT FROM DC_LIST INTO @CN, @DN;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DomainPath VARCHAR(1000) = SUBSTRING(@DN, CHARINDEX('DC=', @DN), LEN(@DN));
    DECLARE @Domain VARCHAR(1000) = REPLACE(@DomPath, 'DC=', '.')

    SET @strSQL =
    'SELECT sAMAccountName,
            Mail,
            DistinguishedName,
            whenCreated,
            lastLogonTimestamp,
            pwdLastSet
        FROM ''''LDAP://' + @CN + @Domain + '/' + @DomainPath + '''''
        WHERE objectClass = ''''User''''
    '

    [...do the rest of your querying with OPENQUERY...]

    FETCH NEXT FROM DC_LIST INTO @CN, @DN;
END;

CLOSE DC_LIST;
DEALLOCATE DC_LIST;
```

You can insert the results of your OPENQUERY into a temp table while iterating over the cursor and then at the end select your latest login datetime from the temp table.

Comment: Thank you! That got me closer to getting what I need. I was able to use your method to query the AD for all the DC's, and that worked. The problem I am having is in incorporating the individual DC names into the original AD Queries. I use the same query as before, with the newly build LDAP URL (LDAP://MyDomain-DC1.MyDomain.com/DC-MyDomain,DC=com). However, when I execute thequery I get a non-descript error: An error occurred while preparing the query "SCRIPT DISPLAYED HERE" for linked server "MyLinkedServer"

Comment: Yeah, that is a generic fail from the ADSI provider when it either can't parse your query or the query generated some kind of error.  I suggest printing our the SQL and playing with it by itself until the query works, then adjusting your script based on what you fixed.  If you post the SQL I can take a look as well.